# I have a Paramater of a non nullable type error in my MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I'm making a MVC CRUD app that is connected to my SQL Server. I'm trying to get my Details link to populate the info needed. Instead it is coming up with the error that's in this title. I have tried the C# way to fix it, but it populated without Data. I also tried the old google and search the question here and those suggestions didn't net me much. I'm sure it's a easy fix, I just don't know it. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the Error I'm given.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in
>   'MVC.Controllers.CustomerController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Below is my Code, and Proposal_UID is my Key in SQL. 
Here is my code for my RouteConfig

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for my Controller.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                return View(db.Proposals.Where(x => x.Proposal_Uid == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }

        }
```

Here is my Code for my Detail Views

```
@model MVCSQLCRUDnoTelerik.Models.Proposal

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Proposal</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Proposal_Uid)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Proposal_Uid)
        </dd>
 <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start_Date)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Start_Date)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.End_Date)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.End_Date)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I've tried doing this

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                return View(db.Proposals.Where(x => x.Proposal_Uid == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }

        }
```

It populates the page, but not the information needed inside the boxes.

I've also tried doing this

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Proposal_Uid  }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

This is the link that shows when I click on the details link and it goes to the error. I omitted the numbers for #

```
https://localhost:#####/Customer/Details
```

Now when I type the link into the URL I get the correct info and everything

```
https://localhost:#####/Customer/Details/1
```

I know that the problem is in my Views, or Routeconfig file. I just don't know where and no idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCSQLCRUDnoTelerik.Models.Proposal>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Proposal_Uid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.End_Date)
        </th>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Proposal_Uid)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.End_Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: You've shown your Detail view, but not the Index view, which is where I assume the problem lies. Can you include at least the part of Index that generates the link to the Detail action?

Comment: Use the edit button on the question, below the tags. Comments are **not** meant for large blocks of code.

Comment: Ok, I posted it! Now that I see it, I think I haft to uncomment the id=item.PrimaryKey.

Comment: Super. So, I see you have `/* id=item.PrimaryKey */` commented out. What _is_ the ID field for your `Proposal` model? That route value needs to be supplied, or you'll keep getting the error you're seeing. There's nothing (I can see) wrong with your Detail action.

Comment: Proposal_uid is the ID field. I just saw that it was commented out as well. I think that's my problem. it should be `id=item.Proposal_uid` I had no idea that Index also housed the link button code. I thought it was definately on the Details side. That makes sense. Thank you sir!

Comment: You have an Edit link on the Detail view, which would work the same way - it maps to the `int? id` parameter of the action.

Comment: If that works, consider posting a self-answer, describing your fix in a way that helps someone else with a similar issue. I'll help you clean it up, if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is correct/valid:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
    {
        return View(db.Proposals.Where(x => x.Proposal_Uid == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

I would recommend adding a couple of null checks, redirecting to the Index action, just in case:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if(id != null)
    {
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {
            var model = db.Proposals.Where(x => x.Proposal_Uid == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if(model != null)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Comment: thank you! I thought about adding the if statement for null. Now that I see, I will definitely do that.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really answer your question, but is more of a "good practice" suggestion. I think you posting an answer describing what the error was and how you solved it would be more beneficial (if nothing else, it's something you can reference again when you need it).

Comment: So do I just edit the question and mark the box at the bottom that says to answer it, or do I just haft too remake the question and reference this? Or remake the question as a whole?

Comment: No. You should see an "Add Answer" button. Answer this question just like you would any other question.

Comment: @Airizzo For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Sorry, should have read your comment closer. Yes, if you're seeing an "Answer your own question" checkbox, go that route.

Comment: Checked it and answered it. I can't believe I didn't think to check my Index views code. God, I feel silly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206477/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-airizzo).

Answer (score 1):

In my Index Views code,

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCSQLCRUDnoTelerik.Models.Proposal>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Proposal_Uid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.End_Date)
        </th>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Proposal_Uid)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.End_Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The action link is actually commented out with the part that we need. It should look like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Proposal_uid }) |
```

Your C# code for your action (the code that receives the request) should make sure to have the ? in the parameters section as well, so that if anything can be null, it won't populate a error. It should look like this.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
    {
        return View(db.Proposals.Where(x => x.Proposal_Uid == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

There may be other things wrong with the code, but this is such a small mistake that when you create the VIEWS code from the Models by right clicking and creating/scaffolding it automatically comments it out. If you have a key in your SQL table, you must uncomment it out or it will keep generating an error until you do.